# SVG 'stroke-width' changes dimensions of the object

Tags: html, css, xml, svg

I am playing around with SVG images.  In the following code:

```
<svg height="250px" width="250px">
<circle
  r="120"
  cx="125"
  cy="125"
  fill="#334d5c"
  stroke="#e27a3f"
  stroke-width="1px"
/>
</svg>
```

when I increase the `stroke-width` property, it starts to change the radius of the circle, making it smaller.

My questions are:
What is the ratio or rate of change of this process?
How do the additional pixels get added to the radius of the circle?
Is there a way to remove this effect?

Thank you for you time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The radius decreases by half the stroke width.

If you want the circle fill to **not** decrease in size, then the simplest workaround is to have two circles. Put the one with the stroke behind the one with the fill.

But note that, if you use this method, half the stroke width will be hidden by the front circle. So if you need a 10px stroke, you would actually need to set the stroke-width to 20px.

```html
<svg height="250px" width="250px">
<circle
  r="120"
  cx="125"
  cy="125"
  fill="#334d5c"
  stroke="#e27a3f"
  stroke-width="10px"
/>
</svg>


<svg height="250px" width="250px">
  <circle r="120" cx="125" cy="125"
          stroke="#e27a3f" stroke-width="10px"/>
  <circle r="120" cx="125" cy="125"
          fill="#334d5c"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: So to be clear, the radius doesn't change, for instance if you set `stroke-opacity: 0.5` you can see that the fill-area didn't change, what happens is that the stroke spreads in both directions.

Answer (score 0):

The middle of the stroke coincides with the radius of the circle (or more general, the position of a path). Half increases the overall size, half decreases the visible size of the fill.

But that is only a default, because the stroke is painted *after* the fill. You can change that order with the CSS property [`paint-order`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/paint-order). If you set that to `stroke`, the stroke will be painted first, and the fill later, so that it covers the inner half of the stroke.

```html
<svg height="250px" width="250px">
<circle style="fill:#334d5c;stroke:#e27a3f;stroke-width:10px;"
  r="120"
  cx="125"
  cy="125"
/>
</svg>

<svg height="250px" width="250px">
<circle style="fill:#334d5c;stroke:#e27a3f;stroke-width:10px;paint-order:stroke;"
  r="120"
  cx="125"
  cy="125"
/>
</svg>
```

This is supported by all browsers but IE and Edge <17.